# How to make Grunt configuration variables accessible to CoffeeScript files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs

This is my Gruntfile:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({

    site: grunt.file.readYAML('_config.yml'),

    coffee: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: "<%= site.src %>/assets/scripts",
          src: "{,*/}*.coffee",
          dest: "<%= site.tmp %>/assets/scripts",
          ext: ".js"
        }]
      }
    }

  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['coffee']);

}
```

I want to have `app/assets/scripts/globals.coffee` look something like this:

```
jQuery ($) ->

  window.Site = "<%= site %>"
```

How can I interpolate the `site` variable in CoffeeScript files?

I tried using plugins like grunt-contrib-handlebars and grunt-contrib-jst, but those generate JST files which I think isn't what I want.

Comment: Why not just read `_config.yml` in your web app when it starts? If you're using Express, looks like app.locals will do the trick: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals

Comment: How? I don't use Express, I use Assemble.

Comment: What is Assemble? Can you link to it? It probably has some concept of global variables as well.

Comment: [Here it is](http://assemble.io/). It has globals, yes, but I don't know how to embed them into JavaScript files so I can use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like a combination of Yaml and Assemble's Data would do what you need.

http://assemble.io/docs/Data.html

FTA:

> YAML example
>
> Here is the same in YAML format:
>
> `my-template.yml`
>
> > ```
> > title: Assemble 
> > author: Brian Woodward
> > ```
>
> And this template:
>
> `my-template.hbs`
>
> `<h1>{{ title }}</h1>`

You can adapt that to insert a script tag at the top of the page that sets `window.Site = {{site.name}}`.